# Select/highlight entire row on checkbox click

Tags: javascript, jquery, datatables

I want to select entire row of the datatable. With the following code only the 0th(NAME) column from the data is being selected:

I do the following inside a success ajax function

```
mydtable.DataTable( {
    aaData:result.users,
    "aaSorting": [[1,'asc']],
    "iDisplayLength": 25,
    "bPaginate": true,
    "sPaginationType": "full_numbers",
    "scrollY":"350px",
    "scrollCollapse": true,
    "order": [ 1, 'asc' ],
    "dom": 'T<"clear">lfrtip',
    "oTableTools": {
        "sRowSelect":   'multi',
        "sRowSelector": 'td:first-child',
        "aButtons": [ 'select_all', 'select_none', ]
    },

    "aoColumns":
        [
            { "data": null, defaultContent: '', orderable: false},
            { "mData": 0 },
            { "mData": 1 },
            { "mData": 2 },
        ],

});
```

Comment: Without having any clue what library you're using, try changing `"sRowSelector": 'td:first-child',`to `"sRowSelector": 'td',`

Comment: You want to select entire row when ....? The mouse is clicked? And select means ... coloring it? Getting the data?

Comment: @Jamiec "sRowSelector" is used to define what column enables selection. In my case, column 1 has checkbox.

Comment: @davidkonrad When the checkbox is clicked. Select means highlighting as well as data. Right now datatable selects only one column. I want the all the columns ( entire row)

Comment: Are you really using the [datatables plugin](http://datatables.net/) that this question has been tagged with? Your options look nothing like the documentation for that specific plugin? Also note we [dont need tags in the question title](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/19190/should-questions-include-tags-in-their-titles), they're just noise!

Comment: Yes I use the datatables plugin.

Comment: Are you using the latest version of datatables and tabletools? How are you generating the checkbox?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have a look at this demo - http://live.datatables.net/kesijisi/1 - is this what you want it to do?